# Django model instance full_clean method, is this right?

Tags: python, django

What I want to do, is write code that will allow me to bulk-load Django object instances from a csv file. Obviously I should check all the data first before saving anything.

tl;dr: the full_clean() method doesn't catch an impending attempt to save None in a field without `null=True`. Seems perverse. Is this by design, and if so why? Django has fewer bugs than just about anything else I have ever worked with, so "Bug!" seems most unlikely.

Full version. What I thought would work, is for each row, create an object instance, populate fields with the data from the spreadsheet, and then invoke the full_clean method. I.e. (in outline)

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
...

# upload a CSV file and open with a csvreader
errors=[]
for rownumber, row in enumerate(csvreader):

    o = SomeDjangoModel()
    o.somefield = row[0]  # repeated for all input data row[1] ...

    try:
        reason = ""
        o.full_clean()
    except ValidationError as e:
        reason = "Row:{} Reason:{}".format( rownumber, str(e))
        errors.append( reason)
        # reason, together with the row-number of the csv file, fully explains
        # what is wrong.

# end of loop
if errors:
    # display errors to the user for him to fix
else:
    # repeat the loop,  doing .save() instead of .full_clean() 
    # and get database integrity errors trying to save Null in non-null model field.
```

Trouble is, `.full_clean()` does not catch None values in fields without `null=True`

What should I be doing? Ideas include

1. Wrap the whole thing in a transaction, do a batch of o.save() inside an exception handler, and roll the entire transaction back unless there were no errors. But why bother the database when probably 90% of attempts will error out in trivial ways?
2. Feed the data in through a form, even though there is no form-level per-row interaction with the user.
3. Manually test for None where it shouldn't be. But what else does .full_clean not check?

I can understand that ultimately the only way to catch database integrity errors is to attempt to store the data, but why doesn't Django alone catch None in a null=False field?

BTW This is Django 1.9.6

Added detail. This is relevant fields of the model definition

```
class OrderHistory( models.Model):
    invoice_no = models.CharField( max_length=10, unique=True)         # no default
    invoice_val= models.DecimalField( max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)  # no default
    date       = models.DateField( )                                   # no default
```

and this is what is happening, done from `python manage.py shell`, to demonstrate that the .full_clean method fails to spot a n

```
>>> from orderhistory.models import OrderHistory
>>> from datetime import date
>>> o = OrderHistory( date=date(2010,3,17), invoice_no="21003163")
>>> o.invoice_val=None 
>>> o.full_clean()  # passes clean
>>> o.save() # attempt to save this one which has passed full_clean() validation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 820, in _save_table
result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 859, in _do_insert
using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1060, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "invoice_val" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, 21003163, , , 2010-03-17, , null, null, null, null, null, null).
>>>
>>> p = OrderHistory( invoice_no="21003164") # no date
>>> p.date=None
>>> p.full_clean()                           # this DOES error as it should
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nigel/.virtualenvs/edge22/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1144, in full_clean
  raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'date': ['This field cannot be null.']}
>>>
```

Comment: How are None values represented in your csv file? You have an error with code indentation, see last 4 lines where you check for errors and save.

Comment: That's not a code error. I accumulate errors during the loop. After the loop if there were errors I display all of them, otherwise I repeat the loop doing save() instead of full_clean(). (Which might throw database integrity errors, but that's not relevant to this question).

Comment: Null in CSV file is two commas with nothing between them. I'll also treat an all-whitespace string in a numeric column as null (it's a user spacing-out the data instead of deleting it, a common spreadsheet anti-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I have just repeated your steps in shell, and full_clean() triggers ValidationError for None values:

```
>>> from orders.models import OrderHistory
>>> o = OrderHistory()
>>> o.full_clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/oz/.virtualenvs/full_clean_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1144, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: {'date': [u'This field cannot be null.'], 'invoice_val': [u'This field cannot be null.'], 'invoice_no': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}
```

I've tested it on fresh project with Django 1.9.6 and Python 2.7.10 on OSX and Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu.

Try removing all *.pyc files from your project. If that doesn't work, remove your virtual env, create new one and reinstall your dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not an answer to the question. What I want to know, is why the full_clean method fails to detect these nulls. Certainly I can add lots of special-case code to check the data myself, but shouldn't Django do this for me given what it knows about the model?

Comment: Like you said yourself, it's very unlikely that this is Django or full_clean() method bug. My guess is that your csv reader is not behaving as you expect and that your empty values (two commas with nothing between them) are not read as python None type, but maybe as blank strings. Can you add some debug logs/prints and check what value and type you get for empty values with print "value: {}, type: {}".format(o.somefield, type(o.somefield))?

Comment: details added to question. Fields not shown have defaults or are null=True. It's `o.invoice_val=None` that gets past full_clean()

Comment: I've updated my answer, I didn't have enough room in comments. :)

Comment: thanks. It's nice to know that it's something in my code, not a misfeature in Django! I'm away from work now until Tuesday next but will update once I work out why I'm getting bad behaviour.